# Javascript jQuery - the method onchange() does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my is problem is.. i try to make a form where i check if the email has the regular expression..when it haves then nothing must happen..but when it not haves ..it must set the feld empty with the method on change()..
i try and must write the code with javascript and jQuery..but nothing happens with my code..
i hope you can help me with this problem
thx..
Here my code:

```
        <div id="formular">
        <p>Hier wird überprüft, ob die angegebene E-Mail Adresse korrekt ist.</p>
        <form>
            E-Mail: <input id="mail" type="text" name="mail" onchange="check();"/>
        </form>

        <script>
            function check(){
            var feld= $("#mail");
            if(feld.value.search(/^([A-Za-z0-9_/\.-]){1,}\@([A-Za-z0-9]){1,}\.([A-Za-z]){2,4}$/)===-1){
                feld.val("");
            }
        }
        </script>

        <hr>
    </div>
```

Comment: check keyup, keydown, keypress, why onchange ?

Comment: Check the console.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+validate+email

Comment: don't use javascript for this, simply use [pattern recognition](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) or the dedicated [input type=email](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern4). Also, concider using `onblur` event, it's simply lots easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using jQuery hence the better way to get to your answer is to use your script in this way:

```
<script>
    function check(){
        var feld= $("#mail");
        if(feld.val().search(/^([A-Za-z0-9_/\.-]){1,}\@([A-Za-z0-9]){1,}\.([A-Za-z]){2,4}$/)===-1){
            feld.val("");
        }
    }
</script>
```

It's because `.value` works for **Javascript** not **jQuery**.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like this, since you are using jQuery. You want this code to run when your document is ready. As you can see I replaced the `onChange`in your input field by a `.change()` call.

You should also use `$(selector).val()` instead of `$(selector).value`.

```
<div id="formular">
    <p>Hier wird überprüft, ob die angegebene E-Mail Adresse korrekt ist.</p>
    <form>
        E-Mail: <input id="mail" type="text" name="mail" />
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var feld = $("#mail");
            feld.change(check);

            function check(){
                console.log("Checking it");
                if(feld.val().search(/^([A-Za-z0-9_/\.-]){1,}\@([A-Za-z0-9]){1,}\.([A-Za-z]){2,4}$/)===-1){
                    feld.val("");
                }
            }

        });
    </script>

    <hr>
</div>
```

**Note** that this only works if you lose focus on the input field. So I am not sure if this is really what you had in mind.